# Does the `hot_standby_feedback=on` may cause `SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected` error?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

On a AWS Master slave hot standby replication schema on Amazon RDS with a single master and a single slave. Both master and replica are being hosted over Amazon RDS on eu-central-1 and the master is used for reading as well. For that we use a rotating dns record that is aliased both on slave and on master database as well.

On my slave database I have the following setting as well:

```
hot_standby_feedback=on
```

I receive the following error on the replica:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7 SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected (SQL: ^some_query^)
```

Also, after further investigations I found out that the error happen both on `insert` and `select` queries as well.

And I try to debug this error. The one issue I thought was the connection capacity that may cause memory starvation. But I was proven wrong:

```
SHOW max_connections;
```

That has value `1722` and the total active connections are about ~17 (without the one that does replication) on my slave database.

Also in the memory in the slave database has no drop as well it stays in a leveled position as seen on this image:

[image: Memory Level on my Database]

Both master ans slave database instances are `db.t3.xlarge` ones. Hence, it has 4vCPUs, 16GB ram and a `100GB` Storage. So being an issue or resources is out of question.

Therefore, I wonder how does the `hot_standby_feedback=on` may trigger this error and how? Also does the replication may cause unexpected connection termination as well because I use a single replica instead of 2 ones?

In the latter case how I can list past server-terminated connections between a time range?

The database connections are performed over a php Laravel application [worker](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues). There are 2 servers that run 4 processes each and for queuing system is used Amazon SQS.

Comment: One cannot be 100% certain, but I'd bet that there is no connection: all that the parameter does concerning communication is that it sends a little extra information back to the master. Can you capture the error and get a stack trace?

Comment: The error is snown like that and because on Stacktrace has production data as well I cannot display more than this.

Comment: Ok, but what process gets the error? The WAL receiver? A client backend? Surely you can disclose some of that information. The stack trace would also be valuable if all sensitive string arguments in it were obfuscated.

Comment: I updated the information regarding the error. I mentioned more info regarding the in stances.

Comment: Thanks. But **where** does that error show up? During inserts on the primary? During queries on the standby? During replication? Which exact component receives the error, and what is it doing at the time?

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to hire a consultant who can come on-site and who will sign an NDA.